# Idiomatic way to proxy named parameters in Clojure

Tags: clojure, amazonica

I need a function that thinly wraps [amazonica](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica)'s `sqs/receive-message` in order to add a default wait time. The function requires a queue URL, and then accepts any number of optional named parameters, which should be passed along to `sqs/receive-message` untouched. I would like to call it like this:

```
(my-receive-message "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123/test-q"
                    :max-number-of-messages 10
                    :delete true)
```

This should result in a call to `sqs/receive-message` like this:

```
(sqs/receive-message :queue-url "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123/test-q"
                     :wait-time-seconds 20
                     :max-number-of-messages 10
                     :delete true)
```

This is something I find myself wanting to do fairly often, but I haven't found a nice way yet. Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `apply` over the merged parameters.

```
(defn my-receive-message
  [url & {:as args}]
  (apply sqs/receive-message (-> {:queue-url url
                                  :wait-time-seconds 20}
                                 (merge args)
                                 seq 
                                 flatten)))
```

Comment: what about destructing the args params? [url & {:as args}] (to avoid the apply hash-map args)

Comment: Also, you probably want to merge the other way around, so the caller of my-receive-message can override the default wait

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! What I missed was `seq`ing the map before I `flatten`ed it.

Answer (score 1):

You could always write a macro:

```
(defmacro my-receive-message [url & opts]
  `(sqs/receive-message 
      ~@(flatten (seq (merge {:queue-url url :wait-time-seconds 20}
                             (apply hash-map opts))))))
```

(Note that this does pretty much exactly the same thing as Guillermo's function. The main difference is that you don't have to `apply sqs/receive-message` -- the unquote-splicing (`~@`) takes care of the `apply` part implicitly.)

Comment: This is really nice, but the words "prefer functions to macros" from every Clojure book I've ever read are still ringing in my ears. ;)

Comment: That is generally a good rule of thumb. Now that Guillermo's function is simpler/sleeker thanks to argument destructuring, I think I would probably go with the function version too. Good call, dAni!